# Visualize the large scale Image datset through graphs

Tags: python

I want my complete image dataset to visualize as a graph in one in Python.
or how to show the color distribution of complete image dataset through a graph or say histogram

Answer (score 0):

Example code

```
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'images'
COLORS = {
    'GREEN': [0, 128, 0],
    'BLUE': [0, 0, 128],
    'YELLOW': [255, 255, 0]
}
images = []

for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
    if not file.startswith('.'):
        images.append(get_image(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, file)))
```

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(1, len(images), i+1)
    plt.imshow(images[i]
```

Comment: import os
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = r'D:\Fusion\Images\train'
COLORS = {
    'GREEN': [0, 128, 0],
    'BLUE': [0, 0, 128],
    'YELLOW': [255, 255, 0]
}
images = []

for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
    if not file.startswith('.'):
        images.append(get_image(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, file))) 
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 10>()
     10 for file in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
     11     if not file.startswith('.'):
-- 12         images.append(get_image(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, file)))

Comment: on running the code i get this error please clarify on that